# weight in neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying neural network feed forward in my anaconda using python3.7 under ipython script.

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1, 0.9])
y = np.array(([0.93], [1]

X = X/np.amax(X, axis=0)
y = y/100
class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #enter code here
        #parameters
        self.inputSize = 2
        self.outputSize = 1
        self.hiddenSize = 3
        #weights
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize) 
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize) 

    def forward(self, X):
        self.z = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2)
        o = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return o
    def sigmoid(self, s):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-s))
NN = Neural_Network()
o = NN.forward(X)

print "Predicted Output: \n" + str(o)
print "Actual Output: \n" + str(y)
```

I would like to know whether I put the weights as random can be change as array like y input value?

Comment: Weights being random sure changes input->output mapping. Maybe what you are asked to do is to update your neural networks weights with backpropagation so that your neural network gives these output values for these inputs.

Comment: Random weight initialization would break the symmetry of the network and thereby give it a chance of optimization.